# what is column of datatype LOB cannot be unique or a primary key error?

Tags: python, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

**my confluent sink properties :**

```
name=sink-oracle
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
tasks.max=1

# The topics to consume from - required for sink connectors like this one
topics=ersin_test

# Configuration specific to the JDBC sink connector.
# We want to connect to a SQLite database stored in the file test.db and auto-create tables.
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter.schemas.enable=true
connection.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.0.0.0:123/abc
connection.user=ersin
connection.password=ersin!
table.name.format=ERSIN_TEST
auto.create=true
delete.enabled=true
pk.mode=record_key
pk.fields=ID
insert.mode=upsert
```

**error**

```
INFO Checking Oracle dialect for existence of table "ERSIN_TEST" (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dia
lect.OracleDatabaseDialect:536)
[2020-04-15 00:31:44,982] INFO Using Oracle dialect table "ERSIN_TEST" absent (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.OracleDa
tabaseDialect:544)
[2020-04-15 00:31:44,982] INFO Creating table with sql: CREATE TABLE "ERSIN_TEST" (
"ID" CLOB NOT NULL,
"PRODUCT" CLOB NULL,
"QUANTITY" NUMBER(10,0) NULL,
"PRICE" NUMBER(10,0) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY("ID")) (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.DbStructure:92)
[2020-04-15 00:31:44,995] WARN Create failed, will attempt amend if table already exists (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.
DbStructure:63)
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-02329: column of datatype LOB cannot be unique or a primary key
```

**json data**

```
{
    "schema": {
        "type": "struct",
        "fields": [
            {
                "field": 'ID',
                "type": "int32",
                "optional": False
            },
            {
                "field": 'PRODUCT',
                "type": "string",
                "optional": True
            },
            {
                "field": 'QUANTITY',
                "type": "int32",
                "optional": True
            },
            {
                "field": 'PRICE',
                "type": "int32",
                "optional": True
            }
        ],
        "optional": True,
        "name": "myrecord"
    },
    "payload": {
        "ID": 1071,
        "PRODUCT": 'ersin',
        "QUANTITIY": 1071,
        "PRICE": 1453
   }
```

**python code:**

```
producer.send(topic, key=b'1071'
              , value=json.dumps(v, default=json_util.default).encode('utf-8'))
```

how can I solve this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connector has attempted to create a table called `ERSIN_TEST`

```
[2020-04-15 00:31:44,982] INFO Creating table with sql: CREATE TABLE "ERSIN_TEST" (
"ID" CLOB NOT NULL,
"PRODUCT" CLOB NULL,
"QUANTITY" NUMBER(10,0) NULL,
"PRICE" NUMBER(10,0) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY("ID"))
```

using as a primary key the `ID` field.

---

> If `auto.create` is enabled, the connector can CREATE the destination
>   table if it is found to be missing. The creation takes place online
>   with records being consumed from the topic, since the connector uses
>   the record schema as a basis for the table definition. Primary keys are specified based on the key [configuration settings](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/sink-connector/index.html#auto-creation-and-auto-evoluton).

For Oracle, by default [JDBC sink connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/sink-connector/index.html#auto-creation-and-auto-evoluton) will map `VARCHAR` to `NCLOB`.

---

You need to change the type of `ID` as fields of type `CLOB` cannot be set as a primary key. To do so, first you need to disallow Kafka Connect from automatically creating the table for you:

```
auto.create=false
```

and now go to your Oracle database and manually create the table but this time, instead of using `CLOB`, use say `NUMBER`:

```
CREATE TABLE ERSIN_TEST (
    "ID" NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    "PRODUCT" CLOB NULL,
    "QUANTITY" NUMBER(10,0) NULL,
    "PRICE" NUMBER(10,0) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("ID")
)
```

and finally re-run your connector.

---

As a side note, don't use single quotes in JSON.